# How to fix image spacing in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to reduce the spacing between the images and the paragraphs of my website. I have tried to remove the space through the draft version, but it appears differently on the actual browser version. Here is the link to the website for reference:

https://pprggw.wordpress.com/partisian-views/

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself; preferably in a Stack Snippet. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [Something in my website/demo doesn't work can I just paste a link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is showing both a margin-bottom of 27px and of 24px on your p tags. Remove both of those in your css and you'll see much less space between the images and the text.

Answer (score 0):

If you can access css for `p` and `.alignnone` you can modify it directly 
or if you cant Add following css

```
#primary .alignnone {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
body #primary p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

if it's working you can try to remove `#primary` and check if it works.
or if you want is not limited to `#primary` div make these styles important
for example

```
.alignnone {
        margin-top: 0 !important;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
    body p {
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
```